# Ruby Methods and Method calls?

Tags: ruby

I am following a beginners course on Ruby, trying to define two methods in the editor:

1. A `greeter` method that takes a single string parameter, name, and returns a string greeting that person. (Make sure to use return and don't use print or puts.)
2. A `by_three?` method that takes a single integer parameter, number, and returns true if that number is evenly divisible by three and false if not.

The error I'm getting is "unexpected end".

```
def greeter(name)
  return "hey" + name + "how are you" + "."
end
greeter(alan)

def by_three?(number)

  if number % 3 == 0
    return true
  else 
    return false
end
by_three?(12)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa: I think it's pretty clear he wants to fix the `unexpected end` error.

Comment: For future questions, you should copy and paste the entire error message... "unexpected end" is ambiguous.  As you can see by the answers provided, you were missing an end statement for the `by_three?` method. There was one `end` for the `if/else` but you needed another end to close the `def`.

Answer (score 2):

You should terminate `if` statement with `end` keyword:

```
def by_three?(number)
  if number % 3 == 0
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Having said that, this method is written really bad, and it can be much simpler:

```
def by_three?(number)
  number % 3 == 0
end
```